# Publishing copyrighted material on GitHub for phishing

Tags: copyright, trademark

I want to publish some demo code on github that deals with a new type of phishing attack. However, I've used a Google-branded sign-in page for the demo. Will this be a problem with copyright or any legal issues?

Comment: why use a specific company branding? publish a generic template and the person using it can re-brand as they wish

Comment: I wanted to show the 'effeciveness' of the code in a related blog post

Comment: Branding is not code. Branding shows the effectiveness of social engineering. That's a completely different matter.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, Google owns their copyrights. I can't say they will for sure sue you for it, but it's their property and they can make that decision if they choose to.